# App.config with dll returns null

Tags: c#, .net, dll, app-config

I have a dll I'm calling from another app. I need to store dll settings in separate xml file. So I'v created App.config file. It is looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="1"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Than I try to get value from config with thic code:

```
var val=System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["myKey"];
```

But it always return null. Also key count of AppSettings equals zero, so there is no keys in it.

What's wrong with it? 
How can I store my settings in separate file?

Comment: App.Config settings come from the application that's running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you're looking for [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration Method (ExeConfigurationFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269(v=vs.110).aspx).

You need to open that assembly configuration file as an another `Configuration` object, and once you've got it, you'll be able to access those `AppSettings`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.

Comment: @Gleb No problem! I'm glad that you solves your concerns :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the configuration mentioned in your question is in in config file of the calling application and not in the App.config of the DLL.